# How to read arguments from ActionExecutedContext in ASP.NET Core ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-action-filter

It is easy to get argument in

```
OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
```

```
context.ActionArguments
```

But how to do it in

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
```

Thanks!

There is no property `ActionArguments` in `ActionExecutedContext`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the action arguments from `HttpContext.Items` and then get it in `OnActionExecuted`:

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Retrieve action arguments from HttpContext.Items
        var actionArguments = context.HttpContext.Items["ActionArguments"] as IDictionary<string, object>;

    }
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Store action arguments in HttpContext
        context.HttpContext.Items["ActionArguments"] = context.ActionArguments;

    }
}
```

Note: since `HttpContext.Items` persists for the entirety of the request, ensure that you use unique keys to store your data to avoid any conflicts.